# Jquery Confirm Dialog box disappears in aspx

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using custom jquery confirm dialog box on button click in aspx page. Problem is that when I am clicking the button the dialog box is coming but automatically closes after some seconds due to autopostback. How to resolve it?

```
Here is my code...

<script>
    $(function confirmation () {
        $('#btnUpdate').click(function () {
            $('#dialog').dialogBox({
                content:'Are you sure to update..!!',
                hasClose: true,
                effect: 'fade',
                hasBtn: true,
                confirm: function () {
                    $('#message').dialogBox({
                        title: 'Confirmation..',
                        content: 'Updated Sucessfully..!!',
                        hasClose: true
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" OnClientClick="return confirmation()" />
```

Comment: Is there any background code defined in the event, `btnUpdate_Click`?

Comment: yes...there is a code behind on `btnUpdate_Click`

Comment: Try updating data using AJAX. If you do it this way the confirm box will disappear.

Comment: Do you want the server side button click event to execute after you click on the confirm on the dialog box?

Comment: yes...after confirmation data is to be updated and and redirect to show refreshed data.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` in `<asp:Button>` to prevent the button triggering the postback.

Sample:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" OnClientClick="return confirmation()" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the event parameter to your click handler, and then [cancel (prevent) the default action](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

```
$('#btnUpdate').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes:

- Cancel the default behavior of the asp.
- Replace the #btnUpdate with #<%=btnUpdate.ClientID%>
- Call the postback when the confirm is true.

Below is the updated code:

```
$("#<%=btnUpdate.ClientID%>").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').dialogBox({
        content:'Are you sure to update..!!',
        hasClose: true,
        effect: 'fade',
        hasBtn: true,
        confirmValue: 'I am sure',
        confirm: function(){
            __doPostBack($('#<%=btnUpdate.ClientID %>').attr('name'), '');
        }
    });
})
```